# accessing GetTransform() property

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

How do I access the GetTransform property of a body which was created in another class? This is what I did, I created a distance joint.

```
distanceJointBodies.Initialize(b, secBody, b->GetTransform(), secBody->GetTransform());
```

I get an error saying:

```
"No viable conversion from 'const b2Transform' to 'const b2Vec2' "
```

pointing to the distance joint parameter:

```
b->GetTransform()
```

where b is a body I created in another class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `GetPosition()` function, not `GetTransform()`, since you have to pass `b2Vec2` to your function